# Angular 2 RC 4 New Animations not supported in Directive

Tags: animation, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

It seems that in current release we can add animations to components only and cannot define them as directives. I mean:

the below works

```
@Component({
    selector: "animate-demo",
    animations: [
        trigger('openClose', [
            state('closed, void',
                style({ height: "0px" })),
            state('open',
                style({ height: "*" })),
            transition("* => *", animate(200))
        ])
```

Whereas the below doesn't work:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "animate-demo",
    animations: [
        trigger('openClose', [
            state('closed, void',
                style({ height: "0px" })),
            state('open',
                style({ height: "*" })),
            transition("* => *", animate(200))
        ])
    ]
})
```

And gives compilation error in visual studio:

```
"Argument of type '{ selector: string; animations: AnimationEntryMetadata[]; template: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ selector?: string; inputs?: string[]; outputs?: string[]; properties?: string[]; events?: strin...'.
```

Usually we might want to have the commonly used animations such as slideDown, sliddeUp, fadeIn, fadeOut defined at one place as a directive and then in components where we want to use them we would just want to import the directive and use the animation instead of redefining animation in each component.

Answer (score 0):

Animation works on a View, directives does not have a view.

You need for reusing animations has a point but it will be done in the component by settings a globally defined animation in the component animation metadata.

It might be that it will be applied into HTML syntax as well, something like a directive but not quite, `<div @my-animation="config here...">`, but this will overlap with trigger state... the API is not set yet.

See this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9668